# Can't download docx with R plumber API on Linux

Tags: r, plumber

I've produced a plumber API that looks like this:

```
#* @serializer contentType list(type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
#* @get /word
function(team){
  tmp <- tempfile()

  render("test.Rmd", tmp, output_format = "word_document",
         params = list(team = team))

  readBin(tmp, "raw", n=file.info(tmp)$size)
}
```

Running locally it works fine on Windows, producing a docx file for download. It also seems to work okay if you run it locally on Linux and use Firefox, although it does seem to crash Firefox as it's trying to open or download the docx file.

But running locally on Linux and downloading via Chrome produces a binary file that is not recognised by the OS. If you select "Open with... Libre Office Writer" the file opens fine, but I really need my users to get a properly formatted file that will be opened automatically.

I can't figure out whether the problem is with the browser or the OS. Any help appreciated.

All the code is in this repository, as I say it all works fine in Windows so I actually put it up thinking it would be a useful reference for others, but now I can't get it to work on Linux- [here](https://github.com/ChrisBeeley/reports_with_plumber)

Comment: This sounds like a browser problem. If the *browser* can't handle a file type, it won't be able to display it. In any case, `docx` is a zip package that contains XML files. You can unzip the file to inspect it and see if it contains the same files in all OSs.

Comment: You should probably force the browsers to download the file instead of trying to display it inline by setting the `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment`, eg with `team$setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myFile.docx")`

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how to get that command working though. Will it work with Plumber? Is it from a package?

Comment: It's the Plumber call that adds a header. Copied [from the plumber tutorials](https://rdrr.io/cran/plumber/src/inst/examples/09-content-type/plumber.R)

Comment: You're a genius! I don't know why I never found that page yesterday, I looked for hours. Many thanks! I'm going to turn the correct code into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

All thanks to Panagiotis, here's the code

```
#* @serializer contentType list(type="application/octet-stream")
#* @get /word
function(team, res){

  res$setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.docx")

  tmp <- tempfile()

  render("test.Rmd", tmp, output_format = "word_document",
         params = list(team = team))

  readBin(tmp, "raw", n=file.info(tmp)$size)
}
```